# Serial connection, open and close for each write?

Tags: java, printing, serial-port

I wrote a Java method to print to serial thermal printer. The current version opens the serial port, prints, and closes the port. I choose this behaviour because I'm used to do it with the file write.
Do you think it is better to open the connection at program startup and close at program exit?

Comment: This depends on the frequency of your writes, I guess. If you write several times a second, say, it is best to keep the fd open for the duration of the program; otherwise you'll have quite a huge syscall overhead.

Comment: What do you think by "better"?

Comment: "Better" in terms of performance, there will be 1 print job every 15 seconds. I don't know if the port open may take a lot of time, from my test I saw it deeply depends on the serial driver: usb-com adapter had take a lot. I post this question because I hope there are a reccomended method to manage serial writings.